# Trapping arrow keys

Tags: perl, keyboard-events

I have a utility that I use as a pseudo "shell". It basically while()'s stdin for commands and runs them through different subroutines.

My question is, is there a module or some example I can use to work toward trapping the up arrow so that I can have it perform a certain action? I plan to incorporate a previous command function similar to bash.

Right now, if I press the up arrow I get this:

```
patrick@utility$ ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try [`Term::ReadLine`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadLine) module